# Total Time computation of Map Reduce job in Hadoop-2.6

Tags: bash, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to compute Total(Elapsed ) time of successful  Map Reduce job( accurately) which is finished just now on  Hadoop -2.6. I want to pass this time in my shell script. I know following ways to compute finish time

- By parsing web interface(`http://192.168.1.169:8088/cluster/apps`) HTML on job completion and extracting Elapsed time.( But problem in this method is some times Hadoop-2.6 web interface hangs for a long time. So this style is not helpful for me. I do not know why does it hangs ? )
- I am using bash script(as mentioned bellow) and writing time in a file( finishTime). But the problem in this is some additional delay of few second is coming and some time it is not giving correct results.

```html
#!/bin/bash
e=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
a=($(mapred job -list all |awk '{print $1," ",$2," ",$3}' | sort -k1 -n  | tail -n 3 | head -n 1))
wait

>finishTime
destdir=./finishTime
>destdir

if [ "${a[1]}" = "SUCCEEDED" ]
then
        total=$(($e - ${a[2]}))
        echo "$total" > "$destdir"
else
        echo $(($(sed -n '1p' < ./init_setting) * 1000)) > "$destdir"
fi
exit
```

- Modification in the job code and printing time on console( But source code of job is not available).

If you know some good way of extracting Elapsed time of a job which is successfully finished just now then please notify me. It will be good if i can extract it via console.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the hadoop command "history", you can use this command print the details information of completed job.

The usage is "bin/hadoop job -history ".“” on the HDFS， that the job dir. e.g.

```
bin/hadoop job -history hdfs://172.16.19.5:9000/output/ >> test
```

note replace the path to yours

the result on the picture[image]

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to initialize History Viewer (on running command hadoop job -history hdfs://enode1:9000/output/ >> ababab )

Comment: The "output" is your job output dir on hdfs ? if not, please replace it use your actual  job output dir